# Unexecuted line executes - Numba

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, jit, numba

```py
@jit(nopython=True)
def f1(x, y):
    #if y is None:
    #    y = x
    y[0] = 0
    x[0] = 0
    return x

@jit(nopython=True)
def f2(x, y):
    if y is None:
        y = x
    #y[0] = 0
    x[0] = 0
    return x

x = np.zeros(5, dtype='complex128')
f1(x, x.real)
f2(x, x.real)
```

If we uncomment in `f1` or `f2`, below error is thrown. Note that `y` is never `None`, so `y = x` shouldn't ever execute. Also, uncommented or not, below won't fail:

```
f1(x, x)
f2(x, x)
f1(x.real, x.real)
f2(x.real, x.real)
```

Am I missing something, or Numba bug?

---

```
  File "<ipython-input-117-a1d860b39413>", line 1, in <module>
    f2(x, x.real)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 415, in _compile_for_args
    error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 358, in error_rewrite
    reraise(type(e), e, None)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numba\core\utils.py", line 80, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)

TypingError: Cannot unify array(float64, 1d, A) and array(complex128, 1d, C) for 'y.2', 
defined at <ipython-input-115-c97d2a6dc56c> (13)

File "<ipython-input-115-c97d2a6dc56c>", line 13:
def f2(x, y):
    <source elided>
        y = x
    y[0] = 0
    ^
During: typing of assignment at <ipython-input-115-c97d2a6dc56c> (13)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it in `numba.jit` with `nonpython=True`, because the python program will be compiled (just like a `c` code), and must be runnable. Unlike python code, that is evaluated at runtime, compiled code must be evaluated in advance, and there is no way for the compiler to guess if `y` is `None`.

To fix this, you can remove the `nonpython=True` (or set it to `False`)

```
@jit(nopython=False)
def f1(x, y):
    #if y is None:
    #    y = x
    y[0] = 0
    x[0] = 0
    return x

@jit(nopython=False)
def f2(x, y):
    if y is None:
        y = x
    #y[0] = 0
    x[0] = 0
    return x

x = np.zeros(5, dtype='complex128')
f1(x, x.real)
f2(x, x.real)
```

but whats the point in using `@jit`, as it will back down to a non-compiled version of the code, with no speed gain? So, you should either reconsider the design of your code, or use it without the `@jit` decorator, as in this case it is useless.

Answer (score 1):

Simple workaround is to wrap the Numba function with a Python function:

```py
def f1(x, y=None):
    if y is None:
        y = x
    assert isinstance(x, np.ndarray) and isinstance(y, np.ndarray)
    return _f1(x, y)

@njit
def _f1(x, y):
    ...
```